# What exactly is "sencha app watch" doing?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6

I'd like to replicate what `sencha app watch` is doing in a custom executable to get more control over the whole process... Watching the file system seems pretty straight forward, but what is it with the `rebuild` that app watch is allegedly doing?
In the documentation it just says (I quote):

> This command watches the current application’s source code for changes
>   and and rebuild the necessary outputs to support “dev mode”.

So what exactly does "rebuild" mean? When I manually run `sencha app build` it takes like forever to finish, while `sencha app watch` is doing it quite a bit faster... So I doubt that this is what it actually does.
A `rebuild` command per se doesn't exist either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing the equivalent of `sencha app build development`. The reason it goes faster is that it keeps the JVM running and it doesn't re-run the initialisation tasks continually.

If you want to take more control of this yourself, the relevant Ant tasks are in the Sencha CMD distribution - most (but not all) Sencha CMD commands are delegated down to the Ant tasks.

It's a little smarter than doing a simple build - because it knows which files have been changed, it knows what steps it needs to do. As such, it won't run redundant steps (another speed win).

One key difference is with CSS - using `sencha app watch` will create the CSS once, and then subsequent edits are processed using Fashion instead.

Comment: I'm a bit curious. You said "won't run redundant steps". But according to the console output it runs a lot of things multiple times. Any idea why that is? https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305749-Console-output-heavily-redundant

Comment: It won't run (as many) redundant steps _once_ it gets to the point where it's waiting for changes. While booting up, it will do a number of things repeatedly - most particularly, every time it goes through a call to Ant, it does start and stop the background server.